# Composite Key with Date Key

Tags: sql-server, date, composite-primary-key

I have a Dimension which uses a composite Primary key to identify a single row (3 keys), and one of those keys happens to be the Date from the Source Table. This Date from the Source i do a Left Join join with the Date Dimension to populate the Fact Table.  Is it a problem that i would have Date in the Fact table (FK_Date) and also in this Dimension?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dim_Stg_Visitor]
(
    [TestCall] INT NOT NULL,
    [VisitorTD] INT NOT NULL,
    [Date] Date NOT NULL,
    [ISP] NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    [Origin] INT NOT NULL,
    [SubOrigin] INT NOT NULL,
    [Page] INT NOT NULL,
    [SubContact] INT NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (TestCall, VisitorTD, Date)
);
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't cause any issues - a `date` is just a simple 3-byte scalar value - what makes you think it might cause issues?

Comment: I am just wondering because the date key will be repeating in the fact table and in the dimension. But guess i have no choice here since it’s part of the composite